# Qwerty keyboard is not working in my Android project

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I developed an application for Android and I executed my application on a device. The app works fine but my device's Qwerty keyboard is not working to enter letters in the EditText widget. How can I enable the keyboard in my app?

Comment: Use Emulator to check your app

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

With this code, you force to show the keyboard.

This to close it again:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Edit:

To get the qwerty keyboard add this line in the layout at the EditBox:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Also when you got the problem that keyboard isn't showing at all, you maybe got this line somewhere in your layout :  `<requestFocus />`, delete this.

Comment: Hi i already used 'InputMethodManager' in my Project,but no use of it.      And one more thing,except numbers & alphabets all keys on Querty keyboard are working properly,but i want to enter alphabets in my EditText using Querty keyboard.

Comment: Modified answer, last 4 lines.